# Jquery serialize does not send input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have a form with input fields which will be triggered every 1 min to update the user entries to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    timer = setInterval(function() { save(); }, 60000); 
});

function save() {
    jQuery('form').each(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:7002/submitStudent.do?requestType=auto&autosave=true",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                if(data && data == 'success') {
                    alert("data saved");
                }else{

                }
            }
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

And here is my form

```
<form name="listBean"> 
    <c:forEach var="Item" items="${listBean.nameList}" varStatus="status">
        <input type="number"name="nameList<c:outvalue='[${status.index}]'/>.initialWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
            <br><br>
        <input type="number" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.finalWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
            <br><br>
        <input type="text" class="formtext" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.Reason" id ="reason<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>" value="" maxlength="255" >
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />

     </c:forEach>
</form>
```

So the ajax calls to the server works fine for every 1 min .But the values entered are not available at the server side.

I am getting the value as listBean.Item.getInitialWeight().

what am i doing wrong ?

Any suggestions are welcome.Thanks for your time ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data: $('#form').serialize(),
```

should become

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

You are referencing to the wrong DOM item

Comment: Or - more specific - add an `id` attribute to your `form` (if you have multiple forms on the page).

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Thanks for your reply. In the real scenario , it already has an id attached to the form and input fields.But I missed out on the example code.Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will treat your

```
$('#form')
```

as "an element with id form". So you should change your jQuery DOM reference.

In your case it can be

```
$('form[name="listBean"]').serialize()
```